# Midi software that monitors your guitar picking accuracy

Tags: midi

My electronic drums can monitor my pad strike accuracy to help improve timing. Is there a software program that does this for a midi guitar interfaced with your computer? It would be an effective tool in helping guys develeop their chops.

Comment: Welcome! Questions looking for a certain kind of product or tool are not [covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you want, you can edit this into an answerable question by, instead of focusing on software or interface, asking the broader question "How can I get data on how accurate my timing is." And as for improving it, good old metronome work is probably best!

Comment: You can do it entirely in audio. Plus it's a bit pointless looking back afterwards to see if you were any good, you need to know right whilst you're playing. Use a strict tempo drum machine & tempo-synced delay. If you're good you can get it to phase. If you're bad it will spiral out of control. See this answer - https://music.stackexchange.com/a/120838/12556

Comment: I disagree about pointlessness of looking back. Pointing out where mistakes happen supports practicing and for a lot of people seeing a score and how it increases when they practice is a huge motivator. There's also a difference between tempo drifting and just clumsy timing without the drift.